# Ordinal Target Variable Prediction in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, imbalanced-data, ordinal-classification

I am trying to put together an ML pipeline in Python (using `Sklearn`, open to alternative package suggestions) where I have 5 categorical feature variables, 2 continuous feature variables, and an ordinal target variable with the following value counts:

```py
0.0    35063
1.0     1073
2.0      496
3.0       52
4.0       13
5.0        4
6.0        2
```

As you might have already caught, the trick here is that approximately ~95% of the target variable is comprised of a `0.0` label. I have put together a pipeline where I am `OneHotEncoding` the categorical feature variables and `StandardScaling` the continuous feature variables.

```py
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('cat', categorical_transformer, categorical_features),
        ('num', continuous_transformer, continuous_features)
    ])

pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[
    ('preprocessor', preprocessor),
    ('classifier', RandomForestClassifier())
])
```

And later applying the following split:

```py
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

Using `Sklearn` metrics' `accuracy_score` functionality, it appears that I achieve a 94% overall model accuracy which is great. However I am worried that due to the skew in the target variable, this model becomes prone to fitting problems. I would really appreciate some insight here.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following points:

- **Class imbalance**: A naïve classifier that always predicts the majority class would be correct 95.5% of the time. Therefore, if your classifier shows an accuracy of 94%, it may not be performing better than a naïve approach. Explore methods to manage the target class imbalance, such as undersampling or oversampling.
- **Classifier for an ordinal target**: The `RandomForestClassifier` does not account for the ordinal nature of the target variable. For algorithms better suited to ordinal targets, refer to this discussion: [Multi-class, multi-label, ordinal classification with sklearn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57561189/8781465)
- **Metric**: As indicated, `accuracy_score` may not be the optimal metric for your scenario. A high `accuracy_score` does not guarantee a useful classifier. Furthermore, it disregards the ordinal nature of your target variable. For example, an `accuracy_score` treats predicting `0.0` instead of `6.0` the same as predicting `5.0` instead of `6.0`. Investigate metrics that more accurately reflect the cost of misclassifying an ordinal target:  [Measures of ordinal classification error for ordinal regression](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/338904/measures-of-ordinal-classification-error-for-ordinal-regression)
- **Splitting**: As desired when dealing with imbalanced data, `train_test_split` by default splits in a stratified way. This means that each split will contain roughly the same proportion of each class in each split. When implementing cross-validation, make sure to use a stratified approach as well, for example with `StratifiedKFold`.

With a little bit of research on these points I am certain you will find a good solution to your problem.